# Getting all Posts Wordpress in Json with URL

Tags: json, wordpress, bots, posts, messenger

I use the link : http://MYWEBSITE/wp-json/wp/v2/posts to see all the posts of my Wordpress.
But in fact it doesn't show ALL. It only shows the posts with the "post-type" equals to "post" in the data base. I have others with the "post-type" as "blog".

I can't find where I can have an URL that will give me the JSON of these blog posts.
So if you have any idea tell me !

It's for a Messenger bot, that will get all posts so as to show them when the user ask for it.
I didn't managed to use PHP in Glitch.com, so if you have an idea on this too.. :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should expose your custom post type. For the reference use [documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/).

```
 /**
  * Add REST API support to an already registered post type.
  */
  add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type_rest_support', 25 );
  function my_custom_post_type_rest_support() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    //be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
    $post_type_name = 'blog';
    if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base = $post_type_name;
        $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
    }

  }
```

Then you can access it trough `http://MYWEBSITE/wp-json/wp/v2/blog`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I read the Doc, but the problem now is that it's in PHP. As I said I didn't managed to use PHP in Glitch.com, is it possible ?
It could solve the problem.

At the same time I started using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-rest-api . Allowed me to get the Posts only once again. I tried to do as they did to "discover" my website, but it seems that it can't find the route, maybe because it doesn't already exist. So I'm stuck once again, if you have time to check this doc and se if you have an idea on what to do, I would appreciate.